# Can't open python programs from command prompt

Tags: python, windows-7, cmd, command-prompt

When attempting to run .py files from the command prompt I get this,

```
C:\users\ocean>python helloworld.py
python: can't open file 'helloworld.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The environment variables are already set to ;C\python27 and ;C\python32 (yes, I'm running both releases of python.)

Do I have to set a new variable? What must I do? Running Windows 7, it was a pain to get it to even run that error, before 'python' wasn't even recognized.

Edit: C:\users\oceans does not include my python folder. Is there anyway to redirect the directory so that I won't have to move all of the python files to ocean?

Comment: Is helloworld.py in the directory C:\users\ocean ? Do you get a Python console when you type `python`?

Comment: type `dir` in command-prompt, so we can see if you have python file in current folder

Comment: What does `dir` in that subdirectory give? Check permissions on the file?

Comment: Ahh, the the file isn't in C:\users\ocean, I don't know how that passed me, is there anyway to redirect the directory so that I won't have to move all of the python files to ocean? 

And yes. the python console appears when I type 'python'

Comment: @user1106259 I suggest to edit your question with this new information, otherwise, your probably going to get more downvotes

Comment: Instead of moving files, change working directory in command prompt, type `cd directory\with\your\files`, if your files not on c:\ disk, type `d:` before `cd dir...` (d - your disk letter)

Answer (score 2):

You have to either do:

```
python c:\path\to\the\file.py
```

or

```
cd c:\path\to\the
python file.py
```